# Find $ff...f(x) [100 times]$ of $\frac{1-x}{x^2+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Possibly the idea is to work out $ff(x)$ and $fff(x)$ and find a repeating pattern, but even to find $fff(x)$ seems a lot of work, suggesting I'm on the wrong track.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the result has a nice short formal expression?

Comment: ${1 \over x} - {2 \over 1 + x}$.